# How to select all the subplots with spanSelector?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got a question when I am using the [SpanSelector](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/span_selector.html#span-selector) widget of matlotlib.

- **What I need to do**: Select a span among all the subplots in a figure, all the subplots should be synchronized.
- **What I did**: Create a SpanSelector for every subplot, with

```py
for i in len(self.channel_list):
    ...
    self.signal_span_selectors[i] = SpanSelector(self.signal_ax[i], onselect=self.update_signal_span,
                                                 direction='horizontal', useblit=True,
                                                 props=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red'), interactive=True)
    ...
```

- **What I got**: As we can see the picture below, I can only select span separately in different subplot.

What I got:
[image: What I got]

- **What I want is**: No matter where I select the span, all the subplots should be synchronized, they should between the same x-axis. Like the picture below.

What I want is:
[image: What I want is]